# @ControllerAdvice not catch the thrown exceptions

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I use java spring.
I try to use ControllerAdvice in my project as a global event handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionsHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(RestClientException.class)
    public void RestClientException(RestClientException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("RestClientException" + ex.getMessage());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    public void Exception(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception" + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In this function I create and throw an exception:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Scheduler {

    public void schedule() throws JsonProcessingException, Exception {
            throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

And:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RestfulReaderServiceImpl implements RestfulReaderService {

    public String getData(String url) throws RestClientException {
        throw new RestClientException();
    }
}
```

But when those functions are fired and exceptions are thrown the exception handlers
in class ExceptionsHandler does not execute.

Any idea why exception handlers in ExceptionsHandler class not catches and handles the
exceptions?

Comment: I completely missed  that those weren't `@Controller` classes. `@ControllerAdvice` is meant to be used as part of Spring MVC. It's not clear how you intended to use it.

Comment: I want to use a global exception handler in my project, it's not MVC or any RESTful API project.
Any suggestion can I use?

Comment: That's not what `@ControllerAdvice` is meant for (it's really just an annotation, it doesn't do anything by itself). You haven't shared enough detail about how it's meant to be used, but [this might get you started](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler--).

Answer (score 1):

`@ControllerAdvice` only handles exceptions thrown from Controller methods i.e. methods annotated with `@RequestMapping` or any of its shortcut annotations (`@GetMapping` etc.). You can check this by calling your exception throwing method from any `@RequestMapping` annotated method.

Comment: I don't use MVC in my project.
Is it good practice to use @RequestMapping in a non-MVC project?

Comment: @Michael `@RequestMapping` annotations are not limited to MVC only. If you are creating any API or more specifically any RESTful API than you have to use `@RequestMapping` this is default way of handling `http` requests in Spring.